# Javascript Jquery execute code after external stylesheet changed / re-loaded the promise way

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a page with couple of themes and allow users to change via a combobox. On `change` event of combobox, I use jquery to remove current stylesheet and append new one. Now I want to run some code after the new stylesheet has completed loading (to recalculate size of elements,...).

I wonder if I can do it the **promise** way? Currently I'm using `setTimeout` but the timing is not good enough in my eyes. I'm thinking of something like:

```
var oldStylesheet = ...;
var newStylesheet = ...;

$.when(function() {
    var d = $.Deferred;

    oldStylesheet.remove();
    newStylesheet.append();

    // when new stylesheet completed loading: d.resolve();

    return d.promise;
}).done(function() {
    // code to run after new stylesheet has completed loading
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  `$.get()` AJAX function in jQuery for your use-case, assuming that the value of your option in your combobox is the url of the stylesheet:

```
var oldStylesheet = ...;
$('.theme-select').on('change', function(){
  var stylesheet = $(this).val();
  $.get(stylesheet , function(response){
   oldStylesheet.remove();
   // Check if the style tag in which the file will be appended is in place
   // if not create one
   if (!$('.custom-theme').length){
       $('head').append('<style class="custom-theme"></style>');
   }
   // Add/Replace the new style with the old one.
   $('.custom-theme').text(response);
  });
});
```

I haven't tested it though so I don't know if there are errors or what-not.

Comment: This could help with the time needed for loading new style sheet from server but there still the time needed for browser to re-render the styles. On an ancient browser/PC, this will be a problem as you try to calculate elements' sizes which are still not re-rendered yet. This is all theory but I'll do tests and update later. Thanks!